# How can I connect to bluetooth headphones from command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I have a pair of bluetooth headphones that, when started (or restarted) don't always trigger my computer to automatically connect to them. In those cases I have to go into the sound menu, find the headphones on the list of playback devices and right click -> connect.

Thats kind of tedious. Is there a way to do this from command line?

Answer (score -2):

You can simply make the headset as the Default Playback Device. This should work and is a simple solution.

Comment: They already are marked as such, it doesn't work for me for some reason. Also, this doesn't answer how to do it from command line.

Comment: There are no straight paths to achieve this as Bluetooth is not a Microsoft implementation. However, you can use certain command line tools. These are installable tools. Please see http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/ This includes example for each tool and a batch script which is likely to do the thing. 
About the default playback device. Again, this is not really a smooth operation. It depends on the hardware, BT parameters specified or configured, timeouts and whether the discovery is turned on/off (System) or off (on both ends).

Comment: In win10 Windows has its own drivers for most things, including Bluetooth, so there probably is a CLI for it.

Comment: There is no straight built in command line support for BT. There are Powershell commands to do some tasks as well as APIs and programming support. You gotta use a script rather than using a simple command like in Linux. I hope someone else would provide a better answer. Thanks.